# Uncheck the 3 Transfom checkboxs

Tags: transform, maxscript

I try to uncheck the 3 Transfom checkboxs on the hierarchy menu in one click.
I search on google and and I can't find any information abuot this,
only how to turn them all ON or OFF with the bitArry (#all and #none).
And how to turn on specific checkboxs with the bitArry (example: #{1,3,7}).
I wrote this script:

```
rollout menu02 "Separated Axis" 
(   

    label type01 "--- TRANSFORM ---"

    button b3 "LOCK" pos:[40,30] width: 80
    on b3 pressed do
        (
            setTransformLockFlags selection #{1,2,3}
        )

    button b4 "UNLOCK" pos:[160,30] width: 80
    on b4 pressed do
        (
            setTransformLockFlags selection #{} --?????????????????
        )
)
```

What I need to type (on the last line (--?????????????????)) to uncheck only the 
Transfom checkboxs without effecting the Rotation and Scale checkboxs in case they are ON?

Same Question for check them ON without effecting the others.

Thakns :)

Answer (score 0):

```
for obj in selection do
    setTransformLockFlags obj (getTransformLockFlags obj - #{1..3})
```

Same with plus instead of minus to check instead of uncheck.